# PHP to Edit XML, POSTed from iOS

Tags: php, ios, xml, xcode, post

It's simple...I need to take user-input fields from my app, and add them as child elements in an XML.  I have looked a little at SimpleXML but could use some guidance on the IOS side of things to POST it to PHP and have the PHP add it to the XML.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php

Answer (score 0):

```
For uploading image with user information use this link
```

[Trouble Passing Variables to PHP Script on Image Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698986/trouble-passing-variables-to-php-script-on-image-upload/20699710#20699710)

```
For just uploading user information use this link
```

[Send JSON request with iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038551/send-json-request-with-ios/22039350#22039350)

```
For uploading multiple images
```

[how to GET or POST multipart data request in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061478/how-to-get-or-post-multipart-data-request-in-php/22062088#22062088)

hope this will help you